# How to capture output of function in for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a for-loop that calls a function. The function iterates over elements in a list and constructs vectors from it. I am able to print out each of these vectors put since I need to perform operations on them I need the loop to actually return each of them.

```
for text in corpus:
        text_vector = get_vector(lexicon, text)
        print(text_vector)
```

Comment: Create a list in which you can store the elements returned by your function

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a list.

You can create a list by doing:

```
output = []
```

Then in the loop you can add the values like this:

```
for text in corpus:
        text_vector = get_vector(lexicon, text)
        print(text_vector)
        output.append(text_vector)
```

Now you have saved each item from the for loop in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think only you need is a list in the global scope and append to it.

```
vector_texts = []

for text in corpus:
        text_vector = get_vector(lexicon, text)
        vector_texts.append(text_vector)
        print(text_vector)
```

Comment: Yeah I should have mentioned I already tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I missed a line. When I post my browser crashed. then I submit the draft